# How to show Size Swatch Option in Reverse Order in magento2

Tags: magento2, swatches

`Swatch option coming in asc order but i want to show in reverse order!`

> Is any way for that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yo! Yo!
Find a Solution!

Open File

> vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/ResourceModel/Attribute/OptionSelectBuilder.php

Add Below code on after line no. 93
`)->joinInner(
    ['attribute_option' => $this->attributeResource->getTable('eav_attribute_option')],
    'attribute_option.option_id = entity_value.value',
    []
)->order('attribute_option.sort_order DESC'`